# Multiple constructors in Ruby C++ extension

Tags: c++, ruby

I build the ruby C++ extension. i have multiple constructors in C++. so i did create several initialize methods. but it show an error.
Thank you.

here is my code.

C++ header file

```
  #ifndef CIRCLE_H_
  #define CIRCLE_H_

class Circle {
    public:
        Circle():_radius(0.0) {}
        Circle(float radius):_radius(radius) {}
        float getArea() { return 3.14159 * _radius * _radius; }
        void setRadius(float radius) { _radius=radius; }
    private:
        float _radius;
};

#endif /* CIRCLE_H_ */
```

cpp file

```
   #include<ruby.h>
   #include"Circle.h"
   #include<iostream>

   using namespace std;

   VALUE classOb;

   template<class Obtype> void delete_objects(Obtype *ptr){//   free pointer
     delete ptr;
   }

   template<class Obtype> VALUE wrap_pointer(VALUE klass,Obtype *ptr){ //wrap c++ object to ruby object
       return Data_Wrap_Struct(klass,0,delete_objects,ptr);
   }

   VALUE alloc_ob(VALUE self){
       return wrap_pointer<Circle>(self,new Circle());//  add c++ object to ruby     object
   }

   VALUE method_initialize(VALUE self,VALUE y){
       double x= NUM2DBL(y);
       Circle *c;
       Data_Get_Struct(self,Circle,c);
       c->setRadius(x);
       return self;
   }

   VALUE method_Initialize(VALUE self){
       .......
       return ;
    }
    ............

    extern "C" void Init_Test(){
    VALUE lemon = rb_define_module("Test");
    classOb= rb_define_class_under(lemon,"Circle",rb_cObject);
    rb_define_alloc_func(classOb,alloc_ob);
    rb_define_method(classOb, "initialize", (VALUE(*)(ANYARGS))method_initialize,0);
        rb_define_method(classOb, "initialize", (VALUE(*)(ANYARGS))method_initialize,1);
    rb_define_method(classOb, "test1", (VALUE(*)(ANYARGS))method_initialize,0);
    }
```

extconf.rb

```
   require 'mkmf'
   have_library( 'stdc++' );
   $CFLAGS << " -Wall"
   create_makefile( 'Test' );
```

test.rb

```
  require 'rubygems'
  require '/home/kelum/workspace/Test3/circle/Test'
  include Test
  obj=Circle.new
  obj2=Circle.new(7.1)
```

errors occur

```
  Circle.cpp:47:61: error: overloaded function with no contextual type information
  Circle.cpp:48:61: error: overloaded function with no contextual type information
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two `initialize` methods that take different params and have Ruby choose between them for you. This is a limitation of Ruby, and is different behaviour to C++ constructors. Technically the Ruby `initialize` happens post-construction anyway - Ruby has already made the object, and does so without using any params.

Instead, you have two options

**1) Allow `initialize` to take a variable number of params, and detect the different possibilities yourself.**

The initialize method:

```
VALUE method_initialize( int argc, VALUE* argv, VALUE self ) {
  VALUE y;

  // You'll want to read up on rb_scan_args
  rb_scan_args( argc, argv, "01", &y );

  Circle *c;
  Data_Get_Struct( self, Circle, c );

  // Only set radius if y is not nil
  if ( ! NIL_P( y ) ) {
    c->setRadius( NUM2DBL(y) );
  }

  return self;
}
```

How to bind it to a class:

```
rb_define_method( classOb, "initialize", method_initialize, -1 );
```

(Notice the `-1`, Ruby's signal that the method takes a variable number of arguments)

**2) Use "factory" methods with different names, and handle building the new object yourself.**

The factory method:

```
VALUE method_from_radius( VALUE self, VALUE y ) {
  double x= NUM2DBL(y);

  volatile VALUE new_circle = alloc_ob( self );

  Circle *c;
  Data_Get_Struct( new_circle, Circle, c);
  c->setRadius(x);

  return new_circle;
}
```

This variation is also possible (and perhaps closest to what you were aiming for):

```
VALUE method_from_radius( VALUE self, VALUE y ) {
  double x= NUM2DBL(y);
  return wrap_pointer<Circle>(self,new Circle( x ));
}
```

How to bind it to a class:

```
rb_define_singleton_method( classOb, "from_radius", method_from_radius, 1 );
```

Note that singleton methods have different behaviour to instance methods when manipulating them in Ruby. You may need to `extend Test` as well as `include Test`.

Comment: No problem. Note that the "factory" method approach would let you use your different C++ constructors, but only if you do that via some new variations of `wrap_pointer<Circle>(self,new Circle( ));` - I will show that above for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you try to bind two constructors:

```
    Circle():_radius(0.0) {}
    Circle(float radius):_radius(radius) {}
```

Ruby has no overloaded methods and it stucks with it.

Try to remove default constructor and pass default value to another one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. it works when only use one constructor. is there any other way to bind two constructors?

Comment: Generally speaking, **no**. But there are some workarounds, like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Ruby.html#Ruby_nn20). I did not try it myself, but I’ve heard it works.